# Drupal 6 - How to add 2 strings in CCK Computed field?

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-fields

I have a CCK Text field called: `field_fb_field_b`

I have a Computed field called: `field_fb_link_computed`

In my computed field I have 2 variables called:

```
$var1 ="some text";
$var2 ="some more text";
```

I wanted my Computed fields to add something like:

```
$node_field[0]['value'] = $var1.$node->field_fb_field_b[0]['value'].$var2
```

Is this correct?

I want to display `field_fb_field_b` in a View I have created. But the `field_fb_field_b` shows empty!

Answer (score 0):

Use views templates for fields. In each template you can use $row array to access for all values of row.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, am new to Drupal. Can't I just use temporary variables in the Computed CCK Field and add the string?

Comment: I can't find any Views templates for fields in Site Building -> Views. Also, from your comments $row array will only display values stored in a field. I don't want to store $var1 and $var2 in a field. I just want to store 1 value in a field. Then use a computed field to output its value as something like - > $var1.$node->field_nameoffield[0]['value'].$var2